# Linker errors LNK2001 and LNK2019

Tags: qt, compiler-errors, linker, lnk2019, lnk2001

I am compiling my Qt project using compiler MSVC2008, and I am getting linker errors like-

_class_name.obj_:error **LNK2001**: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject...."... referenced in a function "_function_name_"

_class_name.obj_:error **LNK2019**: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct QMetaObject..." ... referenced in a function "_function_name_"

I have few basic queries-

1. what does it mean by errors LNK2001 and LNK2019?
2. Why these error occurs?
3. How to resolve these?

**NOTE:** I am using QtCreater so build system uses qmake and compiler used is MSVC2008.

Comment: It looks like you use signal/slots without compiling and linking the metaobject information.

Comment: What buildsystem are you using? Is it qmake or are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes. I am using QtCreater so its qMake and compiler I am using is MSVC2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In a nutshell, you used a function which is declared but not defined.
2. It should be caused by your classes using Qt functionality (like signal-slots) but incorrectly.
3. Here's possibilities I can think of:

   3-a. Double check you've written "Q_OBJECT" at the beginning of your class that use Qt functionality.

   3-b. You call "moc" property, i.e. check if your Qt Visual Studio plugin is installed and enabled.

Comment: I do not see the OP mentioning Visual Studio... It is possible that QtCreator is used for this...

Comment: True, the OP said "compiler MSVC2008". I thought it was just "MSVC2008". Another possibility is that he's using cc.exe directly.

Answer (score 0):

You've included the wrong/too little files or forgot to add .lib files to the Linker in msvc.

Check under linker's `Additional Dependencies` property for:
`QtCore5.lib` - for Qt5 Release
`QtCore5d.lib` - for Qt5 Debug

`QMetaObject` is included in one of those, but they might not be the only dependencies in your project.

Comment: This is `Qt5Core.lib` or `Qt5Cored.lib` now.